# Why use private classes when you can use public?

Tags: c++

So I've just started out learning C++ and I've learned that public can be used in main()
while on the other hand private can not unless you're using a function that is public in order access private. Can anyone give me an example of when you would use public and private classes in a real life project. So far all I've been C++ for is outputting text on consoles. I've learned that classes are very important and would like to understand when to use private and public.

Comment: Sorry, but the question "what are classes for" is far too broad to be asked here. Read further introductions into c++, that is all explained.

Answer (score 1):

Private classes are used when you don't want to expose the information out side that class. For example, you don't want that the instance of your class to be created out side the class. It will be just used to provide info using public methods as ans when required.

```
.. when you would use public and private classes in a real life project.
```

Lets say you are creating a Bank application, you need to return few values regarding the confidential info of a bank customer like A/c number, bank balance etc. You will create public methods to give the access of this info and you should never make the BankInfo class public but private, so that, no user can create instance of it out side the class. In short, the behavior of the secured data will be defined by the methods/classes which are public.

```
.. unless you're using a function that is public in order access private.
```

This point has nothing to do with private class. The private members of class should be accessed by Public methods.

However, the same objectives can be achieved using other OOP concepts also.

Hope this makes sense and clearing your doubts.

Comment: that actually helps a lot thank you! but what are OOP concepts?

Comment: Its a very much broad topic, I would recommend you to refer this links for that - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep OR http://oopsconcepts.blogspot.com/

Comment: @Robert: that's like asking "what are physics concepts" :) Well, not to that degree, but still, the answer to such a question can be found in entire books, not in one answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Robert If this answer satisfies your query, then please consider accepting it as a correct answer.!

Answer (score -1):

The keyword here is `encapsulation`. It is very fundamental idea of object-oriented programming.

Comment: This should have been a comment, but is certainly not an answer for such a broad question.

Comment: And it's not that correct, either. The very fundamental idea of object-oriented programming are virtual functions.

Comment: It is correct. There are more than one fundemantal ideas and both encapsulation and polymorphism are among them, although researches haven't agreed on any official, god-approved list.